# What are the two long components on the board?

Tags: hardware

On the Raspberry Pi there are two components about an inch long, one next to the ethernet and one next to the logo. I have been wondering since I received the device what these components are?

These are the components I'm referring to.

[image: RPi - Components]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this diagram](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ko3USNjwacI/Tu-PHNQGZLI/AAAAAAAACqo/kYGIyGWFV5Y/s1600/Raspi-Model-AB-Mono-1.png), they are your CSI and DSI connectors, for camera and display, respectively.

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, I did not realise they were I/O, but now I see that the black tops can actually lift up. Thanks for the help, I had always presumed the JTAG headers were for the camera/display modules!

Comment: For anyone interested, it seems the JTAG headers that I referred to are used to give access to the chip, although they require data files that we do not yet have access to. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/263/38

Answer (score -2):

Camera & display ribbon cable slots.
FYI the display ribbon cable slots in correctly only one way.
The camera connection will accept the ribbon cable either way!

Comment: does not add anything.